# Why does Pylint error on metaclass-defined attribute usage?

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributes, metaclass, pylint

I am using a metaclass in my code, and the code works. (Using a metaclass, it sets the attribute `test_attr` to `"Success!"` on object creation.) When I run `pylint` on this code, however, it displays errors in `Test.test`, saying that `test_attr` is not defined.

```
class MyMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs):
        attrs["test_attr"] = "Success!"
        return super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs)


class Test(metaclass=MyMeta):
    def test(self):
        return self.test_attr
```

What should I do to satisfy `pylint`? Is there a configuration option to fix this? Is there something about my code that I should fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing pylint simply doesn't understand this kind of "magic" - why are you doing it in the first place?

You could set `generated-members` or `ignored-classes` (see [docs](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) to tell pylint about it.